# A question about initializing a newly created empty string in Java

Tags: java, string

I am reading the source code of [`String.java`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk16u/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) in OpenJDK *jdk16u*.

One of its constructors is shown as follows:

```java
    /**
     * Initializes a newly created {@code String} object so that it represents
     * an empty character sequence.  Note that use of this constructor is
     * unnecessary since Strings are immutable.
     */
    public String() {
        this.value = "".value;
        this.coder = "".coder;
    }
```

Apparently that `.value` refers to this private `byte` array:

```java
    /**
     * The value is used for character storage.
     *
     * @implNote This field is trusted by the VM, and is a subject to
     * constant folding if String instance is constant. Overwriting this
     * field after construction will cause problems.
     *
     * Additionally, it is marked with {@link Stable} to trust the contents
     * of the array. No other facility in JDK provides this functionality (yet).
     * {@link Stable} is safe here, because value is never null.
     */
    @Stable
    private final byte[] value;
```

This means that when we use String() as a constructor, this.value references `"".value.` However, I can't find the exact definition of `"".value`.  It seems to me like a circular definition.

Edit: it's not circular definition. what I mean is that how does Java know that "" means empty string.

Comment: Using `"".value` simply causes the string to be an empty character sequence rather than an undefined value which could cause all manner of issues.

Comment: The definition of `"".value` is "the `value` field of the empty string". How is this circular? Note that `this` is not the same object as `""`.

Comment: @sorifiend exactly what issues are thinking about? because I find this constructor really dumb

Comment: the only use case of this is when you would want to define a new empty String, not being a literal. When _exactly_ that would make any sense is beyond me

Comment: @sorifiend Do you mean that when computer compiles the code "".value, it will detect that ""means an empty string so it will create an empty string object and initialize its value as a char[0] (new char[]{})

Comment: @Sweeper  it's not circular. what I mean is that how does Java know that "" means empty string and also I didn't find the definition of empty string constructor.

Comment: `String` doesn't have just this one constructor, does it? The object representing the empty string can be created using a constructor other than the one that you've shown here, right? I haven't looked into which one it is exactly though.

Comment: @Sweeper yes. what I really need to make clear is : for empty string "", what is its constructor. However, I can't put a break point to see how this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the object being constructed. the empty string represented by the literal “” is an already existing string object, which is separate from the object being constructed. value is a private field on String. The code assigns the pre-existing empty string value to the new object’s value. There is no circularity here.

It is a bit weird that an object can see another object’s private members, this is allowed inside a class definition as long as the other object has the same type. Usually you see this in equals methods.

Literal syntax for String is coded into the compiler. Different JVM languages allow different literal syntaxes for different kinds of objects, the syntax is part of the language. Groovy, Clojure, and Scala all have very different literal syntaxes for various things. Rules for literals are spelled out in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5

Comment: 1+, already constructed is the key here. Now, why in the world such a thing is needed? do you happen to know?

Comment: @Eugene: like you I think it makes no sense. They must’ve wanted String to have a zero arg constructor for something but who knows what.

Comment: So actually the compiler can detect that "" represents empty string?  Then for empty string, what is the corresponding constructor?  using public String(char value[]) ?

Comment: @LeonloveKaren: I don’t see that the spec tells what constructor to use. It would definitely not use the no arg one.

Comment: To sum up, what I really need to make clear is : for empty string "", what is its constructor. However, I can't put a break point to see how this happens.

Comment: That would be an implementation detail up to the jvm.

Comment: Well, it's going to be an empty array of characters.  And  this code is just reusing one that's already in the string pool.